# In kabbadi, why did the referee give a card to the coach?

Tags: rules, kabaddi

In Vivo Pro kabbadi, Dabang Delhi vs Puneri Paltan, in the last minute of the match the referee gave a green card to Dabang Delhi's coach. The coach is not playing. The coach is not in the kabbadi court; then why did the referee give a green card to the coach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referee and the umpires shall have the power to warn, declare technical point against, temporarily suspend or to disqualify any player or team from the match who is committing any violation, also ***Coaching from outside by the coaches and the players***.

***Green Card*** is for initial warning for any violation of rules.
As coach intentionally/deliberately give commands/instruction/orders to players. So that's why card is given.

***Reference:***
https://medium.com/@Khel_Gyani/green-card-yellow-and-red-cards-in-kabaddi-7bc02b1f2c48